# How to make a disappearing glow effect

Tags: css

Let's say i have a button class

```
.mat-cancel-color {
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    color: #dddddd;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

and whenever i click something(not the 'mat-cancel-color' button) i want this class to gain a glow effect which would fade away over .4s.

should i create a new class and then give that class the box-shadow(glow) property, then below  transition-duration property and then the the box-shadow(no glow) property again? as such:

```
click-class {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px rgba(255,255,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px rgba(255,255,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px rgba(255,255,0,1);
transition-duration: .4s;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,0,1);
}
```

or does transition-duration only work when switching classes or does it also work when switching properties inside a class? if it as such, how should i go about it?

EDIT: mistook transition-delay with transition-duration.

Comment: why don't you want to show a sample in a snippet here ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ + https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Setting up the same property won't work. CSS will read the class selector from top to bottom, meaning all the `box-shadow` properties above the `transition-delay` will get negated and only the following will get applied when the class is added. What you want is a CSS animation.

Comment: @disinfor yeah, i wanted to ask about that, hit up an answer and i'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a CSS animation. Mainly because you don't want the default state with the glow, that's why `transition` won't work here.

```css
.mat-cancel-color {
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.mat-cancel-color:hover {
  animation-name: glow;
  animation-duration: .4s;
}


.mat-cancel-color-trans {
  width: 160px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0);
}


.mat-cancel-color-trans:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 10px rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="mat-cancel-color">Button</button>

<button class="mat-cancel-color-trans">Button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you man, i always find trouble with animations, so i try to avoid then as much as possible.That's why i though i might cheeze it out with a transition-duration or something along the lines :)

Comment: No problem. I also added a `transition` version for the second button to show why `transition` doesn't work in this case - when mousing out, the transition reverses, which I'm assuming is not the desired effect.

Comment: oh, now i get what you meant, that clarifies a lot, Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some psudo classes like this:

```
:active:not(*element/class*) {...}
```

and then put the glow animation that you want within the brackets. `:active` is a psudo class that is only applied when the element named is clicked. `:not()` excludes the class listed in the parentheses. As long as you have the glow animation working fine, then this should work.
This is a snippet of my test code:

```
a:active:not(.mat-cancel-color) {...}
```